# Asking if variable is equal to an integer inside jquery click not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, onclick

The title really explains most of it, but basically, this should alert when I get the click the element, but it doesn't. It also *does* work when I put the alert() outside of the if, and in the beginning of the jquery on click. Here's my code:

```
var hasClickedWelcome = 0;

//Onclick event
$(".menu-welcome" ).click(function() {
    var welcomeButton = document.getElementByClassName("menu-welcome");
    if(hasClickedWelcome == 0) {
        alert("hello");
        $(".menu-welcome").addClass("menu-welcome-clicked");
        hasClickedWelcome = 1;
    } else {
        welcomeButton.classList.remove("menu-welcome-clicked");
        hasClickedWelcome = 0;
    }
});
```

Comment: `hasClickedWelcome == hasClickedWelcome` is always true.  I think you want `if (hasClickedWelcome == 0)` there.

Comment: There's no function `getElementByClassName`. It's `getElementsByClassName` and it returns a `NodeList`, not an element. Why don't you just use `$(".menu-welcome")` instead of `welcomeButton`?

Comment: Did you define hasClickedWelcome any where?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your if statement has no meaning

```
if(hasClickedWelcome == hasClickedWelcome)
```

This will always return true, you'll always hit this code no matter what:

```
alert("hello");
$(".menu-welcome").addClass("menu-welcome-clicked");
hasClickedWelcome = 1;
```

Therefore, you have a clear logic problem.

Edit: See Daniel Beck suggestion on comments section

Comment: That was just a problem with when I put the code in this post, the problem still persists.

Answer (score 0):

Initially, you have syntactic error, there is no inbuild function like  `document.getElementByClassName()` (unless its your custom function), so clearly even if you put your alert in beginning of click it won't work.
Also, you are checking `if(hasClickedWelcome == hasClickedWelcome)` which does not make sense.

Use: `document.getElementsByClassName("menu-welcome");` to get array of nodes having the class. Then, rest of your logic accordingly.

Answer (score -1):

```
//Onclick event
$(".menu-welcome" ).click(function() {
    // in jQuery "this" refers to the element that was selected in a callback
    // it looks like toggleClass is really what you're looking for
    $(this).toggleClass("menu-welcome-clicked");
});
```

Comment: `this` is the element itself. If you want access to the jQuery methods, you have to wrap it as `$(this)`.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question - while it does toggle the class (as intended), your answer doesn't set `hasClickedWelcome`

Comment: @AndyJones I believe this is a simpler way to do exactly what the user is looking for. Seems that the variable is only there to store toggle state. If the asker could give more details about the usage, that would be useful.